# Changing type of object generated by fabric.util.groupSVGElements

Tags: fabricjs

I'm working on an app and depending on what type of object I select in the canvas, I need to show different editing options. So selecting a `textbox` will show font options, selecting an `image` will have filter options etc.

I will also have a list of custom SVGs that the user will be able to load into the canvas. I was thinking of using `fabric.loadSVGFromURL`, like so:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL("https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg", function (
  objects,
  options
) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

  console.log(obj.get('type')) // this returns `group`

  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});
```

This works fine, but when I check the type of the resulting object, I get `group`. I'm already using that to have special group options in the toolbar. I need it to be `svg` or `vector` or anything else really...

Is there a way to edit the type of the objects I add to the canvas? Or use a different way to import SVGs so that I will be able to differentiate between elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not even a minute after submitting the question I tried the following:

```
obj.set('type', 'svg');
```

It worked ...